# How to handle interrupted AndroidHttpClient operation

Tags: android, performance, androidhttpclient

I am using AndroidHttpClient to make a REST API call and get back the result. I am making use of Async to perform network operations. If the internet is lost or exception occurs then I am able to detect and take necessary actions.

My concern is, if the user moves out of the current view how to handle the ongoing Http client execution?

As of now, after every result I check if the UI is still having the the control using findViewById and then populating the result which is tedious considering the amount of REST calls I make and count of screens. If the user clicked on cancel then I call close() of HttpClient to make it stop.

Is there any alternative for handling this with beast performance and coding standards.

Regards,

Harsha

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use try catch block on the onPostExecute method. So whenever you get error you can find on Catch block  :-)